# How to highlight repeated data in alternating columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Exemple: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o6088xXfnEYn-RflrPvY3e_OGJyrI3-tMIb3tFbm6e8/edit?usp=sharing

I have a question about google sheets, columns `id 1` and `id 2` have codes that together result in a unique code like column `unique id.` But, occurs a repetition between columns `id 1` and `id 2` and I would like to know how to highlight that repetition where the unique id is return. Like in row 3 and 8.

---

I try something like this:

`=QUERY(B3:D10;"select B where "JOIN("",C,D)"="JOIN("",D,C)" ")`

`=FILTER(C3:D11;CONCAT(C3:D3)=CONCAT(C3:D3))`

The expected result is something like line 15 of the example.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75460644/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find rows where both IDs are duplicates of IDs found in another row, use `filter()`, like this:

```
=let( 
  data; B3:D11; id_1; C3:C11; id_2; D3:D11; 
  compoundIds; 
    map( 
      id_1; id_2; 
      lambda( 
        c; d; 
        if(c < d;  c & "→" & d; d & "→" & c) 
      ) 
    ); 
  filter( 
    data; 
    countif(compoundIds; compoundIds) > 1 
  ) 
)
```

If you do not have the recently introduced `let()` function yet, use `lambda()` instead:

```
=lambda( 
  data; id_1; id_2; 
  lambda( 
    compoundIds; 
    filter( 
      data; 
      countif(compoundIds; compoundIds) > 1 
    ) 
  )( 
    map( 
      id_1; id_2; 
      lambda( 
        c; d; 
        if(c < d;  c & "→" & d; d & "→" & c) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)( 
  B3:D11; C3:C11; D3:D11 
)
```

To highlight duplicates in the list, use this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule for the range `C3:D11`:

```
=len($F3:$F11)
```

...and fill column `F` with this formula in cell `F3`:

```
=let( 
  ids; B3:B11; id_1; C3:C11; id_2; D3:D11; 
  compoundIds; 
    map( 
      id_1; id_2; 
      lambda( 
        c; d; 
        if(c < d;  c & "→" & d; d & "→" & c) 
      ) 
    ); 
  map( 
    ids; compoundIds; 
    lambda( 
      id; compoundId; 
      if( 
        countif(compoundIds; compoundId) > 1; 
        id & " = " & 
        join( ", "; filter(ids; row(ids) <> row(id); compoundIds = compoundId) ); 
        iferror(1/0) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

...or use the equivalent lambda:

```
=lambda( 
  ids; id_1; id_2; 
  lambda( 
    compoundIds; 
    map( 
      ids; compoundIds; 
      lambda( 
        id; compoundId; 
        if( 
          countif(compoundIds; compoundId) > 1; 
          id & " = " & 
          join( ", "; filter(ids; row(ids) <> row(id); compoundIds = compoundId) ); 
          iferror(1/0) 
        ) 
      ) 
    ) 
  )( 
    map( 
      id_1; id_2; 
      lambda( 
        c; d; 
        if(c < d;  c & "→" & d; d & "→" & c) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)( 
  B3:B11; C3:C11; D3:D11 
)
```

To find rows where id_1 is a duplicate of an id_2 found in the other column in another row, use:

```
=filter( 
  B3:C11; 
  countif(D3:D11; C3:C11) 
)
```

To get the IDs of the duplicates, use `vlookup()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( iferror( vlookup(C18:C; { D3:D11 \ B3:B11 }; 2; false) ) )
```

To highlight duplicates in the list, use this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule for the range `C3:D11`:

```
=countif($C$3:$D$11; C3) > 1
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o6088xXfnEYn-RflrPvY3e_OGJyrI3-tMIb3tFbm6e8/edit#gid=10469098).

As shown above, in the event your spreadsheet locale uses comma `,` as decimal separator, you will have to use semicolon `;` as formula argument separator and backslash `'\'` as [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) horizontal separator. If your spreadsheet uses period `.` as decimal mark, use comma `,` for both those purposes.

Comment: Is it possible to highlight only when both lines in the column repeat? Not when only one, like number 34 in the example.

Thansss!!!

Answer (score 0):

Added solution to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o6088xXfnEYn-RflrPvY3e_OGJyrI3-tMIb3tFbm6e8/edit#gid=1814143650):

```
=byrow(C3:D11;lambda(z;JOIN("|";TOROW(SORT(TOCOL(z);1;1)))))
```

[image]